# How to find Google Plus business pages for a logged in user using the Google API?

Tags: google-api, asp.net-mvc-5, google-plus

I am looking for a way to get a list of all of the business pages a user has under his account.  The user is authenticated and I can query the API to get data, but I cant seem to find how to get a list of business pages.  Could anyone please direct me where I can find the answer?

Incidentally, I am using MVC 5.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=766) for just such an API method.